# image quality affects CNN performance

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, medical

I am doing a binary classification task on medical images using Inception V3 as the classifier, my training sets and test sets have very different distribution (training sets are extracted from digital whole slide images, test sets are taken by a camera on the top of the microscope), which results in good performance on my validation sets but poor performance on test sets.
I know a good solution is to take training images from the microscope camera as well, but it will cost too much time and manpower. 
A big differece between my datasets for training and testing is the image quality, images taken by the camera have lower quality. Any suggestions to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to transform the training/validation images to be similar to the testing images.
Adding some noise and reducing the input resolution could be enough to start.

Of course if you give us a few example images and share your current NN architecture I can be more precise.